# HTTP header "accept-language" behave differently in various browsers

Tags: javascript, server

i've written the following code in my javascript part of a web page

```
function LanguageClicked(language_clicked){
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        //do something 
    }
  };

request.open("GET", "", true /* async */);
request.setRequestHeader("Accept-Language", language_clicked);
request.setRequestHeader("X-Lang-Change", true);
request.send();
}
```

And in the html code I am transferring to this function the language that the user choose.

When I print using window.alert the `language_clicked` value I get the correct value i.e en-US, or fr.

Until here all is good , the problem I have is that in mobile android native browser - Samsung s7 , user agent:

```
    Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; SAMSUNG SM-A320FL Build/MMB29K)
    AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) SamsungBrowser/5.4
    Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Mobile Safari/537.36
```

when the header arrive at the server it is always the browser default language i.e : en-US. entering the same page from the same mobile just from different browser "chrome" the header arrive as expected to the server.

Is there any information about which browser can i change default http headers field and which are not? or maybe if anyone encountered it before? anything I can do to solve it?

Comment: Use your browser's network tab in developers tools and check if you have `Accept-Language` sent twice.

Comment: on  a mobile browser such as the native android browser etc, i don't see an option of opening network tab or inspect at all.